# Updating primary key values of Table1 with primary key values of Table2 using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

On both tables, the UserID filed is the primary key and the criteria is that the FistName filed value or the MobileNumber filed value must match. The tables look like:

```
Table1
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+ UserID + FirstName + MobileNumber  +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  100   + James     + 07725252511   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  200   + Joy       + 07721323111   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  300   + Pike      + 07820010012   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+

Table2
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+ UserID + FirstName + MobileNumber  +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  100   + James     + 07725252511   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  210   + Joy       + 07721323111   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  31a   + Pike      + 07820010012   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

After Running the SQL, I expect Table1 to Look Like:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+ UserID + FirstName + MobileNumber  +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  100   + James     + 07725252511   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  210   + Joy       + 07721323111   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
+  31a   + Pike      + 07820010012   +
+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

I have this code which runs but is not updating the UserID filed values of Table1 due to key violations error. Any help here?

```
SQL = "UPDATE Table1 " & _
"INNER JOIN Table2 " & _
"ON(Table1.FirstName = Table2.FirstName OR Table1.MobileNumber = 
 Table2.MobileNumber) " & _
"SET Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID, " & _
"Table1.Age = Table2.Age; "

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result are really needed here.

Comment: Hi @Andre I have updated my post with sample data.

Comment: FistName ? :-) Very clan wars

Comment: @Harr, Typo corrected!

Comment: The SQL works as long as you add a space after `ON`, include an `Age` field in the table and I take it `Table1.MobileNumber = 
 Table2.MobileNumber) " & _` should be on one line.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook 1 Yes they are on the same line

Comment: Just thought.... key violation errors.  Is `Table 1.UserID` a numeric field, while `Table 2.UserID` is a text field?  You'll get that error when it tries to put `31a` into a numeric field.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook 1 But in the design view the data types in both fields are set to Short Text.

Comment: I'm not sure then.  Have you tried adding the SQL to a query and running it outside of a VBA procedure? `UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.FirstName = Table2.FirstName OR Table1.MobileNumber = Table2.MobileNumber) SET Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID, Table1.Age = Table2.Age`.  The only problem I've come across is if I don't include an `Age` field in the tables.

Comment: As Darren wrote, run your SQL in an actual query and see if you get better error information (e.g. *which* record(s) are the problem). [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: NO Luck! But on a second thought, Table2 always holds the true primary key while Table1 Adds New Columns and updates if there is any so would It be a good idea to just add the new columns to Table2 and try updating the other rows with values from Table1?

Comment: Yes, add the columns to Table2.  You shouldn't need to add columns to a table after you've built the database.